# Keep a Key Pressed in Python

Tags: python, input, keyboard

I Like to keep a key pressed until a certain time for ex.
I want to Keep key`c` pressed for 5 seconds and release it after that. How can i do so with a python script?
I tried using the keyboard module but can't seem to find a way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe with pyautogui and time ? Pyautogui allows you to control easily your keyboard and mouse.

```py
def hold_C (hold_time):
    import time, pyautogui
    start = time.time()
    while time.time() - start < hold_time:
        pyautogui.press('w')
```